# Java Methods and Arrays

Tags: java

I am just starting out in Java and I have searched through the internet for several hours and cannot seem to find something to help me on an assignment. I have an array and I need to write a method for it. It seems easy but I cannot seem to connect the two together. I understand the methods but we did not go over using them with arrays so I am totally confused. If there is a similar answer on here, please point me in the right direction.

Thank you for your time.

**Question:**

Write a method which takes in an integer from the user between 1 and 10 and determines if that number is part of the randomly generated array. It must have a method signature of (int []) and return a boolean.

```java
public class ArrayExample {

    public int [] createRandomArray() {
        int size = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        int[] array = new int [size];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 10 ) + 1;
        }
        return array;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {       

    }
}
```

Comment: When you already worked with method, then you already know enough to at least start the method. It doesn't matter if you pass `String str`, `int i` or `int[] intArray`, that's all very similar.

Comment: I think you should look at `for-loop`. You may want to loop through your array and compare if each element is equal to the user input.

Comment: Beware that you won't be able to call createRandomArray method within main if you don't set it as `static` (or initialize an ArrayExample object).

Comment: Describe what exactly makes you confused

Answer (score 2):

It will be something like below:

```
public class ArrayExample {

public static int [] createRandomArray() {
    int size = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    int[] array = new int [size];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 10 ) + 1;
    }
    return array;
}

private static boolean checkForNumInArray(int[] randomArrayInput){
  //your logic goes here
  // ask user for input number - Scanner/BufferedReader
  //search for that number in array - Loops
  // if found return true, otherwise return false - if-else
}

public static void main(String [] args) {       
    int[] randomArray = createRandomArray();
    boolean isPresent = checkForNumInArray(randomArray);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, I didn't know ow to set it up. I will get working on it now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the code to have understanding

```
public class ArrayExample {

        public int [] createRandomArray() {
            int size = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
            int[] array = new int [size];
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                array[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 10 ) + 1;
            }
            return array;
        }

        public int getUserInput() {
           //Take input from user and check it is between 1 and 10.
        }

        public boolean search(int[] arr, int input) {
            // Use some searching algorithm. Linear search will suit as the array is randomly generated.
            // if input is present in array return true else return false.
        }

        public static void main(String [] args) {  
           int input = getUserInput(); 
           boolean result = search(createRandomArray(), input);   
           //Print a message based on result.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

In the main method you simply have to iterate the loop of integers from one to ten and check if it is present in the array you have created.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
  int arr[] = createRandomArray(); 
  for(int i=0;i<=10;i++) { 
    if(Arrays.binarySearch(arr, i) == 0) { System.out.println("yes"); } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: no. that doesn't even come close to meet the requirements

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  int arr[] = createRandomArray();
  for(int i=0;i<=10;i++) {
   if(Arrays.binarySearch(arr, i) == 0) {
    System.out.println("yes");
   }
  }
 }

Comment: yes, I know what you meant, but again: no. it doesn't even come close to meet the requirements. It's more than "will it work", the question is "will it work and be designed the way it is asked to be"

Comment: You need a sorted array to use binary search, don't you?

Comment: yes @uneq95 , We cast use Arrays.sort to sort the array